# How to optimize enum assignment in C#

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have got this enum

```
enum NetopScriptGeneratingCases
{
    AddLogMessages,
    AddLogErrors,
    AddLogJournal,
    AllLog = AddLogMessages | AddLogErrors | AddLogJournal,
    DoNothing
}
```

And there is UI with 3 checkboxes so depending which of them are checked I have to generate possible cases to do some job.

```
NetopScriptGeneratingCases netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.DoNothing;

if (checkBoxAddAuditLog.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogJournal;
}
else if (checkBoxAddErrorLog.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogErrors;
}
else if (checkBoxAddLogMessages.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogMessages;
}
else if (checkBoxAddAuditLog.Checked || checkBoxAddErrorLog.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogJournal | NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogErrors;
}
else if (checkBoxAddAuditLog.Checked || checkBoxAddLogMessages.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogJournal | NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogMessages;
}
else if (checkBoxAddErrorLog.Checked || checkBoxAddLogMessages.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogErrors | NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogMessages;
}
else if (checkBoxAddErrorLog.Checked || checkBoxAddLogMessages.Checked || checkBoxAddAuditLog.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogErrors | NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogMessages | NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogJournal;
}


var modifiedFiles = NetopScriptGenerator.GenerateNetopScript(netopScriptGeneratingCases, netopFiles);
```

But I am not sure that this code is a correct... Are there other ways to do it?

Comment: If you're going to use your `enum` as a set of flags as you do by or'ing them together to create `AllLog` then you need to give them values that are powers of 2.   That is you should set the first one to 1, then 2, then 4, and `DoNothing` should be set to 0.

Comment: The way the code is written is flawed I think, since the first check will swallow a lot of other checks; you should try with the most specific and let more general cases to the end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would take what [Chris suggest in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35891723/2307070) and assign your variable like so:

```
NetopScriptGeneratingCases netopScriptGeneratingCases = NetopScriptGeneratingCases.DoNothing;

if (checkBoxAddAuditLog.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases |= NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogJournal;
}
if (checkBoxAddErrorLog.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases |= NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogErrors;
}
if (checkBoxAddLogMessages.Checked)
{
    netopScriptGeneratingCases |= NetopScriptGeneratingCases.AddLogMessages;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned in the comment, the compiler will by default give enums an incrementing integer value, which isn't suitable for using as bitflags. Try amending your definition as follows:

```
[Flags]
enum NetopScriptGeneratingCases
{
        DoNothing = 0,
        AddLogMessages = 1<<0,
        AddLogErrors = 1<<1,
        AddLogJournal = 1<<2,
        AllLog = AddLogMessages | AddLogErrors | AddLogJournal
}
```

Comment: Addendum: to do the opposite, so check which are set, you AND against that field (e.g. `if ( values & Enum.AddLogMessages )`) or a bitmask of 1s to get them all.